# Using Midpoint Rule to Approximate a Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I got this question wrong..

I started by obtaining the following sample points $-.7, -.3, .1, .5, .9$

Next I got my $\Delta x$ with the following computation $\displaystyle{\frac{1.1 - (-.9)}{5} = \frac{2}{5}}$

Comupted $(\frac{2}{5})\cdot(\cos{((-.7)^2)} + \cos{((-.3)^2)} + ... + \cos{(.9^2))}$

Entered answer with multiple decimal places, got an incorrect result. Where did I go wrong? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend drawing rectangles for the midpoint rule.  Check if $\Delta x$ matches the width of the individual rectangles.  You should be able to find your mistake easily after doing this.